# How to access Sylius Services from Custom Controller

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have this Controller in a fresh sylius standard App and I am trying to access some service from the container but the container is always null.

According to the Symfony Docs, all you need to make your controller container aware is extend the Controller class, as I am doing.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomepageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var EngineInterface
     */
    private $templatingEngine;

    /**
     * @param EngineInterface $templatingEngine
     */
    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templatingEngine)
    {
        $this->templatingEngine = $templatingEngine;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        dump($this->get('sylius.factory.product'));

        return $this->templatingEngine->renderResponse('@App/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

is there any additional configuration I need to do? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Update your controller service definition to call setContainer with the container.  Having said that, if you are going through the effort of defining controllers as services then you should simply inject sylius.factory.product into the constructor.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do. Thank you.

Comment: One thing to note that if your are not using any of the base controller helper functions such as getUser or render then there is no need to extend from the framework controller at all.  Independence is often a good thing.